# How to hunt down a rogue keybind in Vim

Tags: neovim

Any time I launch vim, there is a mysterious keybind on the key `Y` that breaks the regular yank functionality. In the output of `:map` it looks like this:

```
n  Y           * y$
```

I should be able to see where it comes from by typing `:verbose :map`, but to my intense frustration, this is the *only* key mapping in the entire output with *no origin*:

```
...
n  )             (ale_next_wrap)
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/Config/nvim/init_keybinds.lua
v  *           * "sy/sgn
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/Config/nvim/init_keybinds.lua
x  S             VSurround
        Last set from ~/.local/share/nvim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim line 608
n  Y           * y$
o  [%            (MatchitOperationMultiBackward)
        Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim line 75
x  [%            (MatchitVisualMultiBackward)
        Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim line 73
n  [%            (MatchitNormalMultiBackward)
        Last set from /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim line 71
...
```

So, short of disabling my plugins one by one until I find the culprit, is there any way to further troubleshoot the origin of this keybind?

Comment: The default key mapping for `Y` is changed to `y$` to align with the feature of `C`, `D` , in [this commit](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/5a111c1b02bbfbc2b42df11d7205153be0893dff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be Neovim-0.6, I guess. For good or bad, it has few `:h default-mappings` builtin. Personally, I just kill'em all ASAP:

```
" disable default-mappings
if has('nvim-0.6.0')
    silent! nunmap Y
    silent! nunmap <C-L>
    silent! iunmap <C-U>
    silent! iunmap <C-W>
endif
```

Comment: Neovim 0.6 breaks `Y` by default..!? Alright, good to know, I guess

Comment: @Hubro There is an irregularity in default keybindings: `C` is `c$`, `D` is `d$`, but `Y` is `yy`. So some people suggest to bind `Y` to `y$` instead. The Neovim team seems to share that opinion.

Comment: That makes sense, but holy crap that goes against 12 years of muscle memory... Seems like an extreme move to change that by default.

Comment: @Hubro I'm agree with you, but this is Neovim, not Vim. They claim "better defaults" whatever that means. And, of course, it's still possible to change all this in a personal config.